# How to reliably identify a certificate as intermediate certificate?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, x.509

As per the title, is there a way to reliably identify a certificate as an intermediate certificate?
I can identify if a certificate is a root certificate. But i can not tell the difference between an intermediate certificate and end/leaf certificate. Is there anything that would? such as one of the extensions?

Answer (score 8):

An intermediate differs from a leaf certificate in that it is allowed to sign other certificates, i.e. basic constraints CA:true. It differs from a root certificate in that it is not self-signed, i.e. the issuer is not the certificate itself.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i was thinking/looking into; the extension: Basic Constraints ( 2.5.29.19 )

Answer (score 2):

Your question sounds like you want to read more about Certificate Path Validation, e.g. in [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-6).

Comment: this would mean i have the complete chain tho. i would like to know without having a complete chain.